# Map enum values fetched from database to string to view on website php

Tags: php, html, mysql, string, enums

I have in my database a column named **bodybuild** which can have **varchar(2)** datatype values ('1','2','3') where 1= six apck 2= fat and 3= thin

How should i map the output coming from my function i.e 1 as sixpack in my view page for view??

```
if (! empty($timeline['bodybuild'])) {
$bbt = \SocialKit\UI::view('timeline/user/info-bodybuild-row');
$themeData['info_bodybuild_row'] = $bbt; }
```

Here the variable **$bbt** contains the enum values. It may be 1 or 2 or 3. I use simple PHP and underscore.js for my website work. I created this variable **$bbt** for an example.

`{{INFO_BODYBUILD_ROW}}` is used to view the value in my view page

Please help and thank you in advance...

Comment: You can use switch case..

Comment: @DhruvilPatel Iam using Iframe to view this data on my page. I dont know why the switch case is not working in my code. Its always showing the default switch case all the time

Comment: Share your switch case code..

Comment: @DhruvilPatel  $bbt = \SocialKit\UI::view('timeline/user/info-bodybuild-row');
   switch ($bbt) { 
     case '1': 
            $bb = "Six Pack";
            break;
     case '2': 
            $bb = "Fat";
            break; 
     case '3': 
            $bb = "Thin":
            break;   
   }
    $themeData['info_bodybuild_row'] = $bb;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$bbt = \SocialKit\UI::view('timeline/user/info-bodybuild-row');
$bbt = ($bbt == 1) ? 'six pack' : ($bbt == 2 ? 'fat' : 'thin');
```

Now you can use `$bbt`

Comment: it's not mapping correctly, I have value 2 on the database but your code is displaying **thin** all the time. Its showing the default value all the time.

Comment: @Yahiya I think you are not getting proper values in $bbt.

Comment: @Yahiya I tested the code; it assumes that the enum values are the only ones possibe. If it's returning `thin`, it's because `$bbt` is neither '1' nor '2'., so the code assumes it's '3'.

Comment: @DhruvilPatel I dont think so. I have checked the values by viewing it as a enum. It show correctly as the database value. The error happen when i use this switch case all the time. switch case viewing default value all the time

Comment: @DhruvilPatel I changed the values and again checked the database. its correctly inserting. I tested it and changed the thin value but the default valie is still viewing

Comment: @Yahiya the values could be correct in the DB but still incorrect when you write store them in `$bbt`. Please `var_dump($bbt)` just before your switch case or before my code to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: @DhruvilPatel as you said i changed the code as `var_dump($bbt) = ($bbt == 1) ? 'six pack' : ($bbt == 2 ? 'fat' : 'thin');`  but there is an error occured. The error message is as follows **500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request**

Comment: @Yahiya no. `var_dump($bbt);` is its own statement. I mean execute it on its own; it should print to the screen information about the value of `$bbt`

Comment: @BeetleJuice I think there something mess with my whole framework. Nothing changes now too... Is it because of the iframe. I used `{{INFO_BODYBUILD_ROW}}` to view the value in my page.????

Comment: @Yahiya sorry I can't help with framework specific questions. I just don't know.

Comment: Its okay @BeetleJuice for your valuable support and time. Keep in touch. again thank you!!!!